# <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p> < o : p > & nbsp ; < / o : p > display error

Tags: php, mysql, outlook, tags

Whenever i receive an email from MS outlook i get this tag < o : p > & nbsp ; < / o : p > (without the spaces) which display's as ? in a <>.

Browser page charset encoding is UTF-8 when i change it to ISO-8859-1 the symbol disappears but my other characters goes wrong. I have to use UTF-8

How can i remove this tag sequence.

PHP language. Storing the mess in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove something in PHP you can use str_replace

```
$string = "<o:p>&nbsp;</o:p> and rest of string";
$searchedstring = "<o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>";
$string = str_replace($searchedstring,"",$string);
echo $string; (Output will be " and rest of string")
```

In this case you just replace the searched string with nothing, but it can also be something else.